# Yii2 gridview - modal only display when click on first row

Tags: gridview, yii2, modal-dialog, kartik-v, yii2-extension

I am using kartik\grid\GridView and kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn to display summary info. On expandRowColumn, I have another gridview to list details info. This part is working fine.

Under expandRowColumn gridview I am using modal to view data for column Details. Click modal on first expandRowColumn working fine but got error on other expandRowColumn row.

There is no error message but modal is not displaying 
[error_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Xh4.png)

Gridview on expandRowColumn

```
$gridColumns = [
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
    'label'=>Yii::t('app','Borderaux No'),
    'format'=>'raw',
    'value'=>function($data) {
        return $data['bordereaux_number'];
    },
    ],
    [
    'label'=>Yii::t('app','Details'),
            'format'=>'raw',
            'value'=>function($data) {

            if ( $data['status'] != 0 ) {

            //modal - list by borderaux no
                $text = '<i class="fa fa-comments-o fa-fw"></i> View';
                $url = '/inpatient/claim/summaryborderauxdetails?status=' . $data['status'] .
                        "&month=" . $data['month'] . "&year=" . $data['year'] .
                        "&search_type=" . $data['search_type'] . "&reimbursement=" . $data['reimbursement'] .
                        "&client_id=" . $data['client_id'] .'&borderaux_number=' . $data['bordereaux_number'] ;
                $options = [
                            'class' => 'summary-borderaux-link',
                            'data-target' => '#summary-borderaux-modal',
                            'data-toggle'=>'modal',
                            'data-id' => $data['bordereaux_number'],
                            'data-pjax' => '0',
                            ];
                return Html::a( $text, $url , $options  );

            }

            },
            'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'text-align:left;'],     'contentOptions'=>['style'=>'text-align: right;'],
    ],];


Modal::begin(['id' =>'summary-borderaux','size'=>'modal-lg','header' => '<h4 class="modal-title">' . Yii::t('app','Details') .'</h4>']);Modal::end();

Pjax::begin(['id'=>'summary_details','enablePushState'=>FALSE]);
echo GridView::widget(['dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'id'=>'summary_details_by_borderaux',
'columns' => $gridColumns,]);
Pjax::end(); 


$this->registerJs("$(function() {
$('.summary-borderaux-link').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
 $('#summary-borderaux').modal('show').find('.modal-body')
 .load($(this).attr('href'));
return false;
});
});");
```

Comment: What error you got?

Comment: There is no error message but modal is not displaying @TomaszKane