# Yii2 gridview - modal only display in other table row if i expand first row

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, kartik-v

I am using kartik\grid\GridView and kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn. Under \kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn gridview I am using modal to create code value. Modal pop up on each and every row on click button New Code Value of expandRowColumn if i keep expand first row of table. But the problem if i collapsed first row and expand any other row and click of button New Code Value modal does not pop up.

Can someone help me? I saw that there is an unanswered topic for the same problem here [Yii2 gridview - modal only display when click on first row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42667602/yii2-gridview-modal-only-display-when-click-on-first-row)

**code-value-master/index.php**

```
<?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'class' => '\kartik\grid\ExpandRowColumn',
            'value' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                return GridView::ROW_COLLAPSED;
            },
            'detail' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                $searchModel = new app\models\CodeValueSearch();
                $searchModel->code_type = $model->code_type;
                $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

                return Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('_codevalue', [
                            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
                            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                            'model' => $model,
                ]);
            },
                    'expandIcon' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>',
                    'collapseIcon' => '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>',
                ],

                'code_type_lbl',

                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{update}'],
            ],
        ]);
        ?>
```

**code-value-master/_codevalue.php**

```
    <?php
    echo Html::button('New Code Value', ['value' => Url::to(['code-value/create', 'cid' => $model->code_type]),
        'title' => 'Create Client Contact', 'class' => 'modalBtnCreate btn btn-success']);
    ?>

    <?php

    Modal::begin([

        'header' => '<h4>Create Code Value</h4>',
        'id' => 'modalCreate',
        'size' => 'modal-lg',
    ]);

    echo "<div class='modalContentCreate'></div>";
    Modal::end();
    ?>

    <?php
    $this->registerJs("$(function() {
       $('.modalBtnCreate').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
         $('#modalCreate').modal('show')
         .find('.modalContentCreate')
         .load($(this).attr('value'));
       });
    });");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your code-value-master/index.php.

```
<div class="modal remote fade" id="codevalueform">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content loader-lg"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Add this inside _codevalue.php

```
<?=Html::a('New Code Value <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>',
                    ['/code-value/create','cid'=> $model->code_type], 
                    [
                        'title' => 'Add',
                        'data-toggle'=>'modal',
                        'data-target'=>'#codevalueform',
                    ]
                   );
                ?>
```

Now inside Code-value Controller

```
public function actionCreate($cid){
    $modell=//your Code here
    return $this->renderAjax('create_form', [
        'model' => $model]);
   }
```

Now create View file for example: create_form.php

```
<div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">New Code Value </h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
```

Run the code, this should work.

Comment: Thank you for your time it slove my problem but in the modal code-type value is not getting dynamically. I slove that problem by adding modal (id => modalCreate) to **code-value-master/index.php**  instead of  **code-value-master/_codevalue.php**.